# Programmatically reading wall posts / stream of facebook "pages"

Tags: facebook

My application is taking in various streams of data from social media / rss and combining it into one feed on the service that I will offer to businesses.

So, I'd like to read facebook page streams and process them.. do I need to get permission from the owner of the facebook page? Or is this publicly accessible somehow? since these are public pages for businesses and not the stream of private facebook users.

I don't care about WRITING to a stream at this point.. just READING.

Comment: Look up the FB.init 'scope' parameter with permission 'read_stream'

Answer (score 1):

If it is public you can read through graph API using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/%page_id%/feed
```

But you need to be logged in, even with a user that does not manage that page.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Facebook API documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/). I think the Graph API and Social plugins can be used for your purpose.